# How can I determine that a given date is the day daylight savings takes effect?

Tags: php, timezone

- PHP timezone is set to America/New_York
- Server is in EDT
- All clients accessing server are in EDT

This year, 2014, Time jumped ahead one hour on March 9th at 2:00 am.

I know I can use `date('I');` to determine if we are in DST or not.  What I need to be able to do is determine if today is the first day of DST (spring or fall)

I'm looking for something along the lines of:

```
function isFirstDayOfDST($date) {
    //Return true if today is FIRST day of DST 
}

echo isFirstDayOfDST('2013-03-09');
//true

echo isFirstDayOfDST('2013-03-10');
//false
```

Is this something I can do programmatically or do I need to maintain an internal calendar of DST dates?

---

**UPDATE**

Based on @MarcB's comment [DateTimeZone::getTransitions](http://php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.gettransitions.php) looks like it gets me what I need, specifically the example on that page from rubo77.

```
function getTransitionsForYear($year=null, $tz = null){
    if(!$year) $year=date("Y");

    if (!$tz) $tz = date_default_timezone_get();
    $timeZone = new DateTimeZone($tz);

    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0') >= 0) {
        $transitions = $timeZone->getTransitions(mktime(0, 0, 0, 2, 1, $year),mktime(0, 0, 0, 11, 31, $year));
        $index=1;
    } else {
        // since 1980 it is regular, the 29th element is 1980-04-06
            // change this in your timezone
            $first_regular_index=29;
            $first_regular_year=1980;
        $transitions = $timeZone->getTransitions();
        $index=($year-$first_regular_year)*2+$first_regular_index;
    }
    $temp   = array_slice($transitions, $index, 2);
    $spring = explode('T', $t[0]['time']);
    $fall   = explode('T', $t[1]['time']);

    $dates = array();
    $dates['spring'] = $spring[0];
    $dates['fall'] = $fall[0];

    return $dates;
};
```

Running `$dates = getTransitionsForYear('2014', 'America/New_York');` gets me:

```
Array
(
    [spring] => 2014-03-09
    [fall] => 2014-11-02
)
```

I've tested for 2015, 2016 and 2017 and all work as expected.

Comment: You can't. daylight savings time is a matter of policy, so there's no algorithm you can use to figure it out. You would have to do as you suggest and keep a data table of DST dates, and then perform a lookup.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.gettransitions.php  should tell you that.

Comment: It would probably be best to maintain the dates on your system and then check to see if the current date matches one of the DST dates you have listed.

Comment: @MarcB, care to make that an answer?  I see how I can use that to get what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Marc B's comment answered the question.  "php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.gettransitions.php should tell you that. –  Marc B"

Since he didn't give an answer I'm answering it myself and marking it CW as described here: [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments?cb=1)